# Template instances conflict during linking

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, linker

When I am building a library (not commonly known, so I will not name it) using VC9 + Win SDK 7.0A, I get errors like the following. And all those errors concern template functions. What can cause it and how to deal with it? -- Append the compiler command and the linker command at the bottom.

I am really disturbed by this. Isn't it a template can be instantiated with same parameters multiple times in many library/object files?

```
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP90.dll) : error LNK2005: 
"class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & 
__cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> > (
class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" 
(??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z) 
already defined in CvBuildLists.obj
```

---

Compiler

```
"(...)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" /nologo /MD /Zi /O2 /Oy /Oi- 
/DNDEBUG /Fp"Release\CvGameCoreDLL.pch" /GR /Gy /W3 /EHsc /arch:SSE2 /Gd /Gm- 
/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /D_USRDLL /DCVGAMECOREDLL_EXPORTS /Yu"CvGameCoreDLL.h" /Zm200 
/Zc:wchar_t- /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
(some library specific definitions) 
/I"(...)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC/include" 
/I"(...)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A/Include" 
/I"(...)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A/Include/mfc" 
/I"(...)\Boost-1.32.0/include" /I"(...)\Python24/include" 
/I"(...)\xerces-c-3.1.1/src" 
/YcCvGameCoreDLL.h /Fo"Release\CvBuildLists.obj" 
/c CvBuildLists.cpp
```

Linker

```
"(...)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\link.exe" 
/out:Release\CvGameCoreDLL.dll /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF 
/IMPLIB:"Release\CvGameCoreDLL.lib" /PDB:"Release\CvGameCoreDLL.pdb" /DLL 
/NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /TLBID:1 /DEF:CvGameCoreDLL.def 
/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT (-- not sure about this, but without it, the mentioned errors looks the same)
/LIBPATH:"(...)\Python24/libs" /LIBPATH:"(...)\Boost-1.32.0/libs/" 
boost_python-vc71-mt-1_32.lib thread.obj exceptions.obj condition.obj xtime.obj 
mutex.obj once.obj recursive_mutex.obj read_write_mutex.obj tss_hooks.obj 
/LIBPATH:"(...)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC/lib" 
/LIBPATH:"(...)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A/Lib" /
/LIBPATH:"(...)\xerces-c-3.1.1\Build\C2C\Release" 
winmm.lib user32.lib psapi.lib 
(many .obj-s and .res) 
(the xerces's lib is actually excluded from building)
```

**edit**

I've forgot. -- The library is build correctly when VC7.1 is used in place of VC9.

**edit2**
`boost_python-vc71-mt-1_32.lib` is not the problem. After removing this file from linking the mentioned errors are still present.

Comment: Have you defined the same function in more than one place? I can half demangle the name in the link error in my head, but I'd need to see the code to help properly without guessing

Comment: Or, you are trying to build someone else's code?

Comment: And do you have a suitable build of boost_python-vc71-mt-1_32.lib  for VC9?

Comment: @doctorlove, what function? Do you mean `std::operator<<`? It is rather not defined by the library I am trying to build. ;) -- And yes, I'm trying to compile not my code.

Comment: I am a little worried about the `/Zc:wchar_t-`. C++ standard requires `wchar_t` to be separate type and I'd expect boost to depend on that. And code compiled with and without `/Zc:wchar_t-` is definitely incompatible and might cause weird linker errors.

Comment: @JanHudec, this is rather not a problem. The code compiles correctly with VC7.1 with this flag (moreover VC7.1 have /Zc:wchar_t- by default, but still you could compile most of things with it). --- I will try to compile something smaller with this boost library and check will it cause some problems. Still, boost's linking looks like some hack and can't figure it out, so I guess, I will have to post next question. -- Here boost is linked by those .obj entries like thread.obj, but this doesn't want to work in a new project. :(

Comment: @Number47: VC7.1 has it as default. But VC9.0 definitely does not. That might just be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your edit suggests the problem has nothing to do with templates, but rather inconsistent inclusion of runtime libraries.
For example, you tell the linker to use boost_python-vc71-mt-1_32.lib and say it's fine with VC7.1 but not VC9.

First, make sure you have suitable boost libraries built for use with the newer version of visual studio.

Second, though it's a related point, make sure any libraries you use are relying on the same runtime.

Comment: `boost_python-vc71-mt-1_32.lib` -- this file is not the problem. I've excluded it from linking and the errors (exactly the same) still appears.

Comment: @Number47: It can be some other library built with different compiler version. The boost_python one just makes it obvious you might have such things.

Comment: @JanHudec, can you explain me why? I am not an expert, but this error looks like, there is the same symbol in msvcprt.lib which is a reference to MSVCP90.dll and in CvBuildLists.obj. So don't get, how other library files can influence it?

Comment: @Number47: Unfortunately I can't. I don't really understand the problem either. However it is known that mixing objects built with different MSC++ versions or mismatched compiler options cause weird errors similar to this one. So I'd make sure everything is built with the same compiler and options before trying to analyse it further.

Comment: @Number47: This kind of error is really most common if you have mismatched compiler flags. The compiler flags you list look correct, but the linker might have mixed up location of the actual offending definition or something like that.